# How to fix the inconsistent response status of FB.login method in React project using Facebook SDK?

Tags: reactjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I am working on a React project that uses the Facebook SDK, but I have a problem with the FB.login method. I want to authenticate users with Facebook, but the response is not reliable. Sometimes, when I close the popup window without logging in, the response status is still “connected”. This is not what I want. I want the response status to be “unknown” if I close the window without logging in. I don’t know why this is happening, and I think I have followed the documentation correctly. It was working once, but after one day when I checked again, it was not working as I expected.
code : -

```
//helper.ts

// This function initializes the Facebook SDK
export function initFBSDK() {
  // Get a reference to the window object
  const fbWindow: any = window
  // Define a callback function for when the SDK is loaded
  fbWindow.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    // Initialize the SDK with your app ID and other options
    fbWindow.FB.init({
      appId: FACEBOOK_ID,
      cookie: true,
      xfbml: true,
      version: 'v14.0',
    })
  }

  // Load the Facebook SDK script asynchronously
  ;(function (d, s, id) {
    let js: any
    const fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
      return
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-const
    js = d.createElement(s)
    js.id = id
    js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js'
    fjs?.parentNode?.insertBefore(js, fjs)
  })(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')
}

//index.tsx 
// Call the initFBSDK function to load the Facebook SDK
initFBSDK()

//Fbpage.tsx
// Define a functional component for the Facebook page
const FBPage:FC = ()=> {

  // Define a click handler function for the login button
  const handleClick = async () => {
    
    // Get a reference to the FB object from the window object
    const { FB } = window as any
    // Call the FB.login method with a callback function and a scope option
    FB.login(
      (res: any) => {
        // Log the response to the console
        console.log(res,'res') // login response
        // Check if the response status is connected
        if(res?.status === 'connected'){
          // Call the FB.api method with an endpoint and a callback function
          FB.api('/me/accounts', (accRes: any) => {
            // Do something with the account data
            
          })
        }
      }, {
        // Specify the permissions you want to request from the user
        scope: [
          'pages_read_engagement',]})
      }
      
     // Return a button element with the click handler attached
     return (<button onClick={handleClick}>handle Login </button>)
      
   }
```